# Running a timer when the phone is sleeping

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer, sleep

I'm building an app and I need a timer to run if the user sends the screen to the background, or if they put the phone in sleep and open it again. I need the timer to still be going.

I tried recording the time when I exit the and enter it again, subtracting the two and adding that to the running count, and it seems to work fine on the Xcode simulator but when I run it on my phone it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here is the code for reference.
And the timer starts with a button I didn't include that part but it's just a simple IBAction that calls the timer.fire() function.

```
var time = 0.0
var timer = Timer()
var exitTime : Double = 0
var resumeTime : Double = 0

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    exitTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceNow
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    resumeTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceNow
    time += (resumeTime-exitTime)
    timer.fire()
}


func startTimer() {
    if !isTimeRunning {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: 
        #selector(WorkoutStartedViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        isTimeRunning = true
    }
}

func pauseTimer() {
    timer.invalidate()
    isTimeRunning = false
}

@objc func action()
{
    time += 0.1
    timerLabel.text = String(time)
    let floorCounter = Int(floor(time))
    let hour = floorCounter/3600
    let minute = (floorCounter % 3600)/60
    var minuteString = "\(minute)"
    if minute < 10 {
        minuteString = "0\(minute)"
    }

    let second = (floorCounter % 3600) % 60
    var secondString = "\(second)"
    if second < 10 {
        secondString = "0\(second)"
    }

    if time < 3600.0 {
        timerLabel.text = "\(minuteString):\(secondString)"
    } else {
        timerLabel.text = "\(hour):\(minuteString):\(secondString)"
    }

}
```

Comment: You said "I tried recording the time when I exit the and enter it again, subtracting the two and adding that to the running count...when I run it on my phone it doesn't work." The code you posted doesn't do that. It uses a timer to increment a count. Don't do that. Save the current (`date()`)  to UserDefaults when you begin the timer. When you enter your function again,  subtract the saved date from the current date. That will be the number of seconds since the timer started, whether your timer method keeps being called or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have the right idea but the first problem I see is that `viewWillDissapear` is only called when you leave a view controller to go to a new viewController - It is not called when the app leaves the view to enter background (home button press)

I believe the callback functions you are looking for are `UIApplication.willResignActive` (going to background) and `UIApplication.didBecomeActive` (app re-opened)

You can access these methods in the `AppDelegate` or you can set them up on a view controller heres a mix of your code and some changes to produce a working sample on one initial VC:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    var time = 0.0
    var timer = Timer()
    var exitTime : Date?    // Change to Date
    var resumeTime : Date?    // Change to Date
    var isTimeRunning = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        startTimer()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive),
        name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
        object: nil)
        // Add willResign observer
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(applicationWillResign),
        name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification,
        object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // Remove becomeActive observer
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                                  name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
                                                  object: nil)
        // Remove becomeActive observer
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                                  name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification,
                                                  object: nil)

    }

    func startTimer() {
        if !isTimeRunning {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector:
                #selector(self.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            isTimeRunning = true
        }
    }

    @objc func action() {
        time += 0.1
        timerLabel.text = String(time)
        let floorCounter = Int(floor(time))
        let hour = floorCounter/3600
        let minute = (floorCounter % 3600)/60
        var minuteString = "\(minute)"
        if minute < 10 {
            minuteString = "0\(minute)"
        }

        let second = (floorCounter % 3600) % 60
        var secondString = "\(second)"
        if second < 10 {
            secondString = "0\(second)"
        }

        if time < 3600.0 {
            timerLabel.text = "\(minuteString):\(secondString)"
        } else {
            timerLabel.text = "\(hour):\(minuteString):\(secondString)"
        }
    }

    @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        // handle event
        lookForActiveTimers()
    }

    func lookForActiveTimers() {

        var timers = [NSManagedObject]()

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Timers")

        //3
        do {
            timers = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            print("timers: \(timers)")

            var activeTimer: NSManagedObject?

            for timer in timers {
                if let active = timer.value(forKey: "active") as? Bool {
                    if active {
                        activeTimer = timer
                    }
                }
            }

            if let activeTimer = activeTimer {

                // Handle active timer (may need to go to a new view)
                if let closeDate = activeTimer.value(forKey: "appCloseTime") as? Date {

                    if let alreadyTimed = activeTimer.value(forKey: "alreadyTimed") as? Double {

                        let now = Date()
                        let difference = now.timeIntervalSince(closeDate)

                        // Handle set up again here
                        print("App opened with a difference of \(difference) and already ran for a total of \(alreadyTimed) seconds before close")

                        time = alreadyTimed + difference
                        startTimer()

                    }
                }

            } else {
                print("We dont have any active timers")
            }

            // Remove active timers because we reset them up
            for timer in timers {
                managedContext.delete(timer)
            }
            do {
                print("deleted")
                try managedContext.save() // <- remember to put this :)
            } catch {
                // Do something... fatalerror
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
          print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    @objc func applicationWillResign() {
        // handle event
        saveActiveTimer()
    }


    func saveActiveTimer() {
        if isTimeRunning {
            // Create a new alarm object
            guard let appDelegate =
              UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
              return
            }

            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            if let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Timers", in: context) {

                let newTimer = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
                newTimer.setValue(true, forKey: "active")

                let now = Date()
                newTimer.setValue(now, forKey: "appCloseTime")
                newTimer.setValue(self.time, forKey: "alreadyTimed")

                do {
                   try context.save()
                    print("object saved success")
                  } catch {
                   print("Failed saving")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT - Here is the full tested and working code on xCode 11.3 and a physical device iOS 13.2 - You have to figure out how to start and stop the timer according to your buttons - but this example simply starts the timer when the app is first opened and never stops or resets it.

You can reproduce this by creating a new single-view xCode project and replacing the code in the first view controller that it creates for you with the code above. Then create a label to attach to the outlet `timerLabel` on the VC

- Also make sure to enable CoreData in your project while creating your new project * Then set up the entities and attributes in the xcdatamodel file:

[image: CoreData setup]

Hope this helps

Comment: I added that code and it worked great. I added my exitTime and resumeTime stuff that I had in my reference code into the functions you wrote. With the simulator, it worked perfectly even when the device went to sleep, but again it didn't work when I ran it on my phone. Is there a particular reason for that or some permission that needs to be turned on?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - does it crash, not call the method/do anything, or not update timers properly?       -         Also what is your project deployment target OS?       -     And your physical device OS?

Comment: I updated the code to a full working sample vc tested on xCode 11.3 and a physical device running iOS 13.2

Comment: It just wouldn't update the time. Basically, if I closed the app at 10 seconds and opened it a minute later it would resume from 10 seconds. However, the updated code did the trick, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: No problem glad I could help! In the code you can see the two important things we must store are the amount of time already timed ('alreadyTimed' - the 10 seconds you are referring to) and the date that the app was closed at ('appCloseTime') -> Then when it opens back up we calculate difference between last open and now and add it to the amount 'alreadyTimed' to get the current time of the timer. CoreData also lets it persist app termination